# Searching in Multi Dimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following parent array and I am trying to get the element that is missing from another array when compared to this parent. Need to compare with module and action to be the same.

```
Parent
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => Masters
        [module] => masters
        [action] => unit_index
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => Appointments
        [module] => appointments
        [action] => appointment_index
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => Transactions
        [module] => transactions
        [action] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => Reports
        [module] => p_reports
        [action] => ds_index
    )
```

)

I want to get the item which is missing from the Parent in the following Child array

```
Array
(
[masters] => Array
    (
        [label] => Masters
        [action] => unit_index
        [module] => masters
     )

[transactions] => Array
    (
        [label] => Transactions
        [action] => 
        [module] => transactions
)
[p_reports] => Array
    (
        [label] => Reports
        [action] => ds_index
        [module] => p_reports
    )
```

)

I tried searching with in_array and also using some versions of the recursive in array but I cant search with multiple keys.

Comment: what is ur expected output?

Comment: The one which is not present in both
Array
    (
        [label] => Appointments
        [module] => appointments
        [action] => appointment_index
    )

Answer (score 0):

[check this page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

PHP 4 >= 4.0.5, PHP 5, PHP 7)

array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful